# arraylist to json in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have 3 string arrays that hold specific strings as follows:

```
String jsonA[] = new String[list.size()];
    String jsonA2[] = new String[list2.size()];
    String jsonA3[] = new String[list3.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        jsonA[i]="title:"+str[i]+"url:"+str2[i]+"banner:"+str3[i];
        //System.out.println(jsonA[i]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(jsonA[i]);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

Let me explain like this:

```
jsonA[] has: str1,str2,str3
                          jsonA2[] has: str4,str5,str6
                          jsonA3[] has: str7,str8,str9
```

I want to make a 3D array that holds like:

```
json3D[i][i][i]       = str1,str4,str7;
json3D[i+1][i+1][i+1] = str2,str5,str8;
json3D[i+2][i+2][i+2] = str3,str6,str9;
```

and finally convert them to json.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the str string array holding? i think your loop might not be working as you expect..

Comment: it holds list array variables. actually it works, but I couldn't figure out how to construct 3d array.

Comment: You could instantiate your 3d array and iteratively store data from your 3 arrays in it, but automatically  converting 3d array to json seems difficult. I'll try with a few json libraries and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your representation of 3D array:

```
json3D[i][i][i]       = str1,str4,str7;
json3D[i+1][i+1][i+1] = str2,str5,str8;
json3D[i+2][i+2][i+2] = str3,str6,str9;
```

which is to hold:

```
jsonA[] has: str1,str2,str3
jsonA2[] has: str4,str5,str6
jsonA3[] has: str7,str8,str9
```

doesn't seem right. The above structure named json3D looks like a 2D array, not a 3D array. Also in a a 3D array, `array[i]` will point to a 2D array, `array[i][j]` will point to a 1D array and `array[i][j][k]` will point to a single item.

if jsonA, jsonA2, jsonA3 are 3 single dimension array, then to store them all together you need a 2D array of size 3X3 holding 9 items (as you showed in your question).

If you have been assigned to use 3d array only then you'll need more data to populate it. Because a 3X3X3 array will hold 27 items, as opposed to 9 here.

That being said, whatever array you need to use - 2D or 3D - you can simply iterate over your 3 1D arrays to populate it and then a simple `new Gson().toJson(array)` will return the appropriate JSON string.